# I have voltage leaking between two wires!

Tags: electrical

I have a home run coming into my master bedroom.   When I checked the voltage it showed 85v instead of 120 and the I checked a power wire in the same box feeding a plug and it showed 15v and when I checked their voltage together it showed 98v.  Could there be a small nail through those two wired at some point?

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring the voltage between hot and neutral? Are you using a contact meter? Non-contact meters can be notoriously misleading.

Comment: You should also check for a voltage difference between neutral and ground. This would indicate a broken neutral connection.

Comment: Yes -- what's the N-G voltage in your master bedroom?

Comment: I would also check the hot to ground if it is 120 or close the neutral is broken someplace or a outlet prior loose in a back stabb. Unless this is the first outlet in the run.

Comment: Something as simple as a loose wire nut could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Any time I measure an undervoltage like that I immediately suspect a broken or floating neutral wire. This is potentially hazardous because it means other outlets and devices in the same house may be seeing an overvoltage.

If you are confident that you have measured those voltages accurately, then all the electrical service in your house may be dangerous. The safest thing to do is turn off the main circuit breaker and call a licensed electrician.

Comment: Over voltage for a broken neutral ? Where are you from ? the only way that could happen would be on a wild leg delta. I don't think this has ever been legal in a home in the U.S.

Comment: See e.g. the fourth case in this answer http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/12552/45091 - what happens when we have an open neutral, and an unbalanced load?

Comment: I have been doing this kind of work for many years and have a degree, it is easy to make a high impedance example when house hold wiring is very low impeadance.

Comment: Well you are an electrician and I am not, so I must advise our audience to defer to your opinion over mine. But I remain convinced that if the neutral bar in the service panel becomes disconnected from the power company, and the outlets and loads on one phase are seeing 85 volts, the outlets and loads on the other phase will see 155 volts.

Comment: I would agree with a neutral from the feeder having funny voltages but not from a 120 home run.

Comment: Just to make it clear there is only 1 phase power to 99.9 % of the homes in the U.S.  This power is 240 V single phase . L1 to neutral is 120 V L2 to neutral is 120 V . L1 to L2 is 240v . This is how the power is supplied. I have worked on maybe less than a dozen houses in my years that were 240/3 or 480/3 and all were y connected.

Comment: I said "phase" when I meant "leg'. Sorry for the confusion. - To be clear, I am talking about the most common U.S. home wiring with 240v split into 120v legs.

Comment: @A. I. Breveleri you're right about the voltage imbalance from broken neutral.  It's all about series and parallel circuitry.

Comment: @A. I. Breveleri also, to be fair,  imbalaced voltage from series circuit cam come from someone accidentally getting a permanent hot fed through a light bulb, or loose wire nuts.